# Syntax error CountIfs-function multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba, syntax, compiler-errors

I would like to use a CountIfs-function with two criterias. My programm should go through two different columns and compare the cells.
I used this code:

`WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Data!E:E;"=Open";Daten!Q:Q;"=company")`

Could you please tell me if it is possible to use the CountIfs-function like that? Because my compiler is dropping a syntax-error.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are your criteria really from two different sheets (`Data` and `Daten`) or is that a typo?

Comment: Oh no sorry it is the same sheet. I just forgot to change both in the english word

Comment: Learn how to use F1.  Put cursor on CountIfs and press F1.  This will open the MS help page on CountIfs.  Start reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Date")
    
    Dim wksFn As WorksheetFunction
    Set wksFn = Application.WorksheetFunction
    
    Debug.Print wksFn.CountIfs(ws.Columns(5), "Open", ws.Columns(17), "company")
End Sub
```